# Visual-Studio Cloud LoadTest run in 32 bits but want 64 bits

Tags: visual-studio, cloud, azure-devops, load-testing

running a Cloud LoadTest from VS2017 on my self-provisioned agents runs 32 bits version of QTAgent (QTAgent32_40.exe). This generates multiple OutOfMemory errors so I want to force the 64 bits version.  How can I do that in VS2017 or VS2015 ?

When running the same test from VSTS, it runs the 64 bits version of QTAgent without requiring any changes.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Hosts" section of the active ".testsettings" file has a selector for 32 or 64 bit operation.

In solution explorer, the context (right click) menu of a ".testsettings" file has a tickable entry for selecting the active file.